# retrieve quantity data from two tables by id and date range

Tags: sql-server

I have two table like

**ItemTable_One**

```
id     itemID    Date           qty
===================================================
1      1         2015-07-1      10   
2      1         2015-07-3      20  
3      2         2015-07-5      30  
4      2         2015-07-7      40
```

**ItemTable_Two**

```
id     itemID    Date          qty
===================================================
1      1         2015-07-2     50   
2      1         2015-07-4     60  
3      3         2015-07-6     70  
4      3         2015-07-8     80
```

I want to retrieve data where **itemID is equal to 1** in a date range.
For example ( date range between 2015-07-1 and 2015-07-30 )

```
itemID    Date          ItemTableOne_qty     ItemTableTwo_qty
============================================================================
1         2015-07-1     10                   0  
1         2015-07-3     20                   0
1         2015-07-2     0                    50
1         2015-07-4     0                    60
```

I've tried `union` join and `subquery` to do it, but I'm very weak in sql query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Because "... I want to retrieve data where itemID is equal to 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.itemID, t2.itemID) AS itemID, 
       COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) AS [Date],
       COALESCE(t1.qty, 0) AS ItemTableOne_qty,
       COALESCE(t2.qty, 0) AS ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_One AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN ItemTable_Two AS t2 ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID AND t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
WHERE COALESCE(t1.itemID, t2.itemID) = 1 AND
      COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31' 
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date])
```

This will put records having the same `[Date]` value in the source tables, into the same row of the output table.

If records of `ItemTable_One` *always* have separate `[Date]` values from records of `ItemTable_Two`, then the `UNION` solution proposed in other answers is preferable.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8906a/6)

Comment: That's exactly what I want :)

Comment: Ughhh !!! ... why not use an inline view for the join, so you can reference the combined columns by name instead of having to repeat the coalesce expressions everyehere....

Comment: @gen-y-s Please feel free to post your proposed solution as a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get all the data you need:

```
SELECT ItemTable_One.itemID, ItemTable_One.Date, ItemTable_One.qty as ItemTableOne_qty, 0 as ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_One
WHERE ItemTable_One.itemID = 1 AND 
    ItemTable_One.Date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-08-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT ItemTable_Two.itemID, ItemTable_Two.Date, 0 as ItemTableOne_qty, ItemTable_Two.qty as ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_One
WHERE ItemTable_Two.itemID = 1 AND 
    ItemTable_Two.Date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-08-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select itemID, Date, qty as ItemTableOne_qty, 0 as ItemTableTwo_qty
from ItemTable_One
where ItemID = 1
and date >= '20150701'
and date < '20150731'

union all

select itemID, Date, 0 as ItemTableOne_qty, qty as ItemTableTwo_qty
from ItemTable_Two
where ItemID = 1
and date >= '20150701'
and date < '20150731'
```

The upper limit for date is intentionally < than the wanted date +1 so that in case it's a datetime that has the time in it, the last day will be included too.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with a `FULL JOIN` or a `UNION ALL` (depending on exact required output)

#### FULL JOIN

A `FULL JOIN` will allow you to get results like you show as long as there are no identical dates between the 2 tables. If such dates are present in both tables, you'd get a single row per date with both values filled.

The query to use is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.itemID, t2.itemID) itemID, COALESCE(t1.Date, t2.Date) Date,
  ISNULL(t1.qty, 0) ItemTableOne_qty, ISNULL(t2.qty, 0) ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_One t1 FULL JOIN ItemTable_Two t2
  ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID AND t1.Date = t2.Date
WHERE COALESCE(t1.itemID, t2.itemID) = 1 AND
  COALESCE(t1.Date, t2.Date) BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-08-01'
```

#### UNION ALL

A `UNION ALL` will allow you to get resutls like you show and will create duplicate rows where the same date exists in both tables. There will always be at least 1 '0' value in any row.

The query to use is:

```
SELECT itemID, Date, qty ItemTableOne_qty, 0 ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_One
WHERE itemID = 1 AND Date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-08-01'

UNION ALL

SELECT itemID, Date, 0 ItemTableOne_qty, qty ItemTableTwo_qty
FROM ItemTable_Two
WHERE itemID = 1 AND Date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-08-01'
```

Comment: A "full join" is just shorthand (eg syntactic sugar) for a full outer join which is also the accepted professional and academic term for this type of join .

Comment: that it might be better to include the accurate full terms and concepts in the explanation, rather than just the (shorthand) syntax.

Comment: @gen-y-s It's not better, its overly verbose and pointless - not any more or any less accurate. You could have just as well claimed that `SELECT` should be `SELECT ALL`

Comment: I'm saying that FULL JOIN is not a term that exist in any text book, it's just a shorthand SQL syntax. It would be better to use the accepted term for this type of query - full outer join.

Comment: In other RDBMSes (e.g. Oracle) you have different syntax rules, such as OUTER JOIN is allowed as shorthand for FULL OUTER JOIN. The point is that these syntactic sugar rules are different and arbitrary across different vendors.

Comment: @gen-y-s - I'd advise you not to make such overarching claims in general and particularly when discussing strictly subjective / opinionated issues. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (bottom), [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm) and [here](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/full-outer-join) for example.

Comment: And also since the questions is specifically about SQL Server, where `OUTER` is explicitly optional, I see no point to this whole discussion

Comment: "LEFT OUTER JOIN" == "LEFT JOIN"   similarly "FULL OUTER JOIN" == "FULL JOIN"  ==> (syntax is) [FULL | LEFT | RIGHT] [OUTER] JOIN , but OUTER JOIN != JOIN , so omitting the OUTER keyword sometimes changes the meaning !!! fail

Answer (score 0):

this will be the other way we can achieve the same result basing on your sample data

```
declare @ItemTable_One table  (id int, itemID int,   Date date,   qty int)
insert into @ItemTable_One values
(1,      1,         '2015-07-1',      10),   
(2,      1,         '2015-07-3',      20), 
(3,      2,         '2015-07-5',      30),  
(4,      2,         '2015-07-7',      40)  

declare @ItemTable_Two table  (id int, itemID int,   Date date,   qty int)
insert into @ItemTable_Two values
(1,      1,         '2015-07-2',     50),   
(2,      1,         '2015-07-4',     60) , 
(3,      3,         '2015-07-6',     70) , 
(4,      3,         '2015-07-8',     80)  

;with CTE AS (
select i.itemID As ItemID1,ii.itemID As ItemID2,i.Date As Dated1,ii.Date As Dated2,i.qty as qty,ii.qty As qty1 from @ItemTable_One i
 CROSS APPLY (select * from @ItemTable_Two )ii
where  i.id = ii.id AND i.itemID = ii.itemID 
)
select * from (
Select ItemID1 As item,Dated1 AS Date, qty,'' as qty1 from CTE 
UNION 
Select ItemID2 As item,Dated2 AS Date,'' as qty,qty1 from CTE)T
--ORDER BY t.qty desc ,t.qty1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline view to simplify horrid sql used in prior answers:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(t1.itemID, t2.itemID) AS itemID, 
         COALESCE(t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) AS [Date],
         COALESCE(t1.qty, 0) AS ItemTableOne_qty,
         COALESCE(t2.qty, 0) AS ItemTableTwo_qty
  FROM ItemTable_One AS t1 FULL OUTER JOIN ItemTable_Two AS t2
  ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID AND t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
) AS v
WHERE v.itemID = 1 AND
      v.[Date] BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31' 
ORDER BY v.[Date]
```